# Does VLOOKUP compare cells

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I am currently using the VLOOKUP function for excel and I was wondering does the VLOOKUP actually compare cells or does it just use the cell straight across from it?

This is my formula "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet3!A2:B1814,2,FALSE)"

[image: Sheet 1 and sheet 2 of my excel document]

As you can see the VLOOKUP function works find for the first product image but it doesnt for the rest of them( it will give #N/A for most of them because the cell in the pic in the right is empty which is ok), but if you look at the picture on the left, cell A4 is the same as cell A3 on the picture on the right and it is still given me #N/A(this is because they are not in the same cells)

So my question is, is there a way for excel to check the table 1(left pic) to see is there a matching name on table2(right pic) by searching the rows?

Thanks

Comment: Post the formula you are using in B4

Comment: i put the formula for B2 in the question there above the picture... the formula for B4 is "=VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet3!A4:B1816,2,FALSE)"

Comment: This is not a programming question. It belongs on [superuser](http://superuser.com). Voting to move.

Comment: @Ken Its a problem with an excel formula that's why it got tagged like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use absolute references for your table array, otherwise the area will be shifted, when you copy your formula down.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet3!$A$2:$B$1814;2;FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

IMG 100243 and 7216 won't work because your formula changes in each row. A really easy way to fix this is to create a named range.

1. In the ribbon go to 'Formulas'
2. Then 'Name Manager'
3. Create a new named range and give it reference to Sheet3!A2:B1814
4. Modify your formula to VLOOKUP(A2, _NAMED_RANGE_ ,2,FALSE)

That should at least resolve that problem. Let me know if that doesn't work