# Excel Vlookup Matching

Tags: excel

I have Column A and Column B. Column A has multiple full names (comma seperated) and column B has one full name. I need to compare the two columns and return true if the full name in Column B matches with any of the names in Column A.

Comment: So basically if the contents of a cell in column B is contained in the cell to the left? Only in that row?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does VLOOKUP compare cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636182/does-vlookup-compare-cells)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cell in column B may be blank, use this:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(FIND(B2,A2)),NOT(ISBLANK(B2)))
```

If it may not, then this will be enough:

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND(B2,A2))
```

Use `SEARCH` instead of `FIND` if you don't need a case-sensitive match.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

To compare B1 to A1, Cell C1 would use the formula:

```
=IF(B1="","",IF(ISERROR(FIND(B1,A1)),"FALSE","TRUE"))
```

Comment: That's what I was trying, but if `B1` is empty, `FIND` returns 1, so it shows "TRUE".